ASP.NET Web API application 'fetch' method working slow and entering 'catch' statement
I am doing a ASP.NET Web API application and I noticed that, for my authentication process, the calling of the API controllers from Javascript gets me in a lot of problems that I couldn't debug myself for more than two weeks now. So I have html pages for login and registration, and, for example for the regsitration, after clicking on the "Register" button, a javascript function will be called which retrieves the information from html and calls the api POST method which will add a new user in my database (I am using EntityFramework InMemory). So here is the function from js:
async function retrieveRegistrationData() {

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
        return false; // Prevent the form from submitting
    }

    const userInput = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
        address: address
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/Users', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userInput)
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            alert(errorText);
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Registration successful!");
            window.location.href = "../pages/login.html";
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
    }
}

Which calls this method:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
    var databaseUserName = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == user.Username);
    var databaseUserEmail = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == user.Email);
    
    if (databaseUserName != null) {
        return BadRequest("Username already exists! Try another username.");
    }

    if (databaseUserEmail != null) {
        return BadRequest("Email already exists! Try another email.");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.IP_Address))
    {
        user.IP_Address = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.ToString();
    }

    _context.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}

Now the problem is, when I input the data in the text boxes and I click on the "Register" button, nothing happens and I get a 'catch' error: "Failed to fetch" and the pages refreshes and nothing adds in the database. If I try again and again, after like 3 or 4 tries it works even though I STILL get the "Failed to fetch" message from the 'catch' statement. This is the same with the log in, I have to try and log in like 3 times before it will work, and I always get the error from the 'catch' statement. I tried to debug it a lot, but nothing worked. I don't get any console errors besides these "Failed to fetch" ones. I tried on more than 5 different networks and everything is the same. I am running the project in 'http'. I would be more than grateful for any advice. Thank you
Tried to remove the 'fetch' and 'async' to not use them anymore, still didn't work. Tried to debug but nothing got close to a solution. I need it to work on the first try.

So when you open the developer console of the browser, what gets send and what is the repsonse? And on the server side: is that User type populated as you expect? What is the exception server side?

So I can see in the console of the browser, in the Network tab, that for the first try I get the error, even if the information is transmitted correctly (I mean the JSON values from the input textboxes) but I can see a difference in the "Initiator" tab that for my first try I only have the Request call stack being "onsubmit" (from html) and the name of the js function, and when I try it the second time, I get the same "Failed to fetch error" but this time I have the route for my Controller Method in the 'Request initiator chain', and my database gets populated. But I don't want to get error

Are you getting to your controller's endpoint? Try setting a breakpoint in the PostUser() method to confirm you're hitting the API and not getting a 404. I reproduced your error utilizing http without all of the database interaction or form logic, then resolved it by fully qualifying the URL in the fetch.
async function retrieveRegistrationData() {
    var email = "testEmail";
    var address = "testAddress";
    var username = "testUsername";
    var password = "testPassword";
    var confirmPassword = "testConfirmPassword";

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
    }

    const userInput = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
        address: address
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5003/Home/PostUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userInput)
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            alert(errorText);
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Registration successful!");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/PostUser")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
    return NoContent();
}

<button type="submit"
        class='input_submit'
        style="margin-right: 15px;"
        onClick="retrieveRegistrationData()">
    Submit User
</button>

